# Can't get SSH access from MacOS host to QEMU Sparc guest

Tags: ssh, osx, qemu

I don't know if I am on the right forum but here's my issue :

I have installed a guest Debian Sparc64 with QEMU on a MacOS 10.9.5. I try to get ssh access between host and guest, without success.

I want to find a simple solution. From what I have seen, I launch Sparc64 with following options :

```
qemu-system-sparc64 -hda debian_sparc64.img -m 2048 -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -nographic
```

Then, I try to connect to guest from my MacOS host with :

```
ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

Unfortunately, the above command doesn't ask a password, it stays locked.

If someone could see what's wrong, this would be fine to let me know.

Regards

**UPDATE 1:**

When QEMU VM is running,

here are the results, on MacOS host, of :

```
nmap localhost -p 22

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-16 22:44 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000097s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

and the results, also on MacOS host, of :

```
nmap localhost -p 2222

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-16 22:45 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2222/tcp open  EtherNet/IP-1
```

I forgot to say that QEMU image used ( debian 9.0 Sparc64 guest) has not by default "SSH server" running on it, as it is showed with this command under root :

```
# ps aux | grep ssh 
root       299  0.0  0.0   7168  1952 ttyS0    S+   22:51   0:00 grep ssh
```

I have nethertheless "SSH Client" (I mean the "`ssh`" command), but I don't know how to connect to MacOS host from the Debian Sparc64 guest.

The problem is that I can't install others packages than ones provided by Debian-Sparc64 QEMU image because I have not the network on this guest ( i.e I can't use `apt-get install` ).

If anyone could see how to circumvent this issue ?

Surely it would be necessary to install networking (port 80) on guest but with a MacOS host, it seems to be difficult, with bridging and virtual interfaces ...

Any help is welcome

**UPDATE 2:**

From `@Stefan M`'s advices, after installing `Squid`, I tried to use `guestfwd` option by launching this way :

```
  qemu-system-sparc64 -hda debian_sparc64.img -m 2048 -net user,guestfwd=tcp::3128-:3128 -nographic
```

and I get the following error :

```
qemu-system-sparc64: -net user,guestfwd=tcp::3128-:3128: could not open guest forwarding device 'guestfwd.tcp.3128'
qemu-system-sparc64: -net user,guestfwd=tcp::3128-:3128: Device 'user' could not be initialized
```

Could you tell me what I have to do (results got with MacOS 10.9.5) ?

**UPDATE 3:**

I have found a tutorial on [this link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/qemu-on-os-x-10-5-running-linux-guest-with-networking.1974866/). Following this page, I did :

1. First Installed TUN/TAP drivers to bridge the NIC from the VM to my OS X host
2. launched QEMU with :

`qemu-system-sparc64 -hda debian_sparc64.img -m 2048 -net nic -net tap,script=no,downscript=no -nographic`

3. Once QEMU has booted, I run into other terminal on Host (MacOS 10.9.5) :
   `ifconfig tap0 192.168.1.21`

Indeed, my local network uses 192.168.1.x IP.

4. Into `/etc/network/interfaces` of guest Debian Sparc64, I have set :

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.21`

Unfortunately, I can't get SSH access from MacOS host to Guest or from Guest to MacOS host (by doing for example : "`ssh user@192.168.1.20`" from host), **even by launching qemu-system-sparc64 with root**.

If someone could see what's wrong.

Regards

Comment: Is the SSH daemon actually running on the Debian host?

Comment: @Kusalananda it is a real problem, the image that I use has no SSH server package installed and I have no networking, so impossible to install it with **apt-get install** . I don't know what to do

Comment: This question helped me get my vm up and working with ssh thanks! What I need to do to get it working was add PermitRootLogin yes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config before I could login. I don't normally allow ssh login with root, but this was a burner vm and I just wanted to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Please try first whether the host is reachable at all. This can easily be done using [nmap](https://nmap.org/). For your case this should suffice:

```
nmap localhost -p 22
```

If it says that the port is open, you should look into the sshd on the guest. If it is filtered, maybe a firewall-issue on your guest (incoming) or your host (outgoing/incoming from local).

### On the update:

Simply put, you have two choices:

1) Use bridged networking for example as described in [here](http://drupal.bitfunnel.net/drupal/macosx-bridge-qemu), that way you can install the sshd.

2) Use **[guestfwd](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#Network-options)**. As you already established a connection (port forwarding) via qemu in one direction, you can easily do the same the other way around:

- Install a proxy on your host (squid, tinyproxy, whatever)
- Point the guest to your proxy: (below untested part of your command):

guestfwd=tcp::3128-:3128

- Last, but not least: Use http_proxy for the apt commands or set the variable system-wide.

When you finally have the sshd running, you should be able to connect to the guest system via ssh.

### On the second update:

If I understand the [documentation](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#Network-options) correctly, you should give the IP-Adresses along as well. My guess is that you try to forward the port to the same host (possibly from guest to guest).

> ```
> guestfwd=[tcp]:server:port-dev
> ```
>
> Forward guest TCP connections to the IP address server on port port to the character device dev

So it should be something along this:

```
guestfwd=tcp:10.0.2.100:3128-tcp:10.10.1.1:3128
```

This would send all connects on the port 3128 from the *guest* to IP 10.10.1.1 to 10.0.2.100.

Comment: -@Stefan M . Can you take a look on my last results into **UPDATE 2** please ?

Comment: -@Stefan M. Thanks for your answer. Nethertheless, I would like to know how choosing correct IP's in your last command "`guestfwd=tcp:10.0.2.100:3128-tcp:10.10.1.1:3128`" : with this range that you suggest, it doesn't work. I tried also with "`-net user,guestfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:3128-tcp:10.10.1.1:3128`" and "`-net user,guestfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:3128-tcp:10.10.1.1:3128`" but without success. Have I to install Squid on guest too (here a debian 9 Sparc 64) ??